¿Cuál es la etimología de apellido "Guinovart"?
There are several people who have the surname Guinovart.
However, the name Guinovart is not listed as a word in many Spanish dictionaries.
¿Cuáles son los orígenes, y cuál es la historia detrás del nombre Guinovart?

Proper names don't have "etylologies". Names of people are not words and therefore not in dictionaries.

Tallett is an unusual name, where did it come from?

Tallett es un nombre inusual, ¿de dónde viene?

Según el Instituto de Historia Familiar, el apellido Guinovart, también escrito como Genovart, Jenovart, Guinovar o Ginovar deriva del nombre germánico Winihard (amigo valiente).
Según Els cognoms i els llinatges dels Vilassarencs de mar, los apellidos  Guinard y Guinart derivan del mismo Winihard.
El sufijo -hard se encuentra en muchos nombres europeos, incluidos nombres españoles en -ardo como Bernardo (cat. Bernat), Leonardo, Gerardo o Ricardo (cat. Ricard).

Pues no es un apellido que suene español y así lo indican aquí

El apellido Guinovart tiene origen catalán. Es un apellido que
proviene de la combinación de las palabras "guin" que significa "hijo"
en catalán y "ovart" que hace referencia a un terreno pantanoso o
desolado. Por lo tanto, el significado del apellido Guinovart podría
interpretarse como "hijo de tierras desoladas" o "hijo de terreno
pantanoso".

Nota: Como indica Jdamian, en la misma página se incluyen diferentes explicaciones. Inicialmente solo vi la primera, que es la citada. Me sumo a su sospecha de que quizás ninguna sea válida. Mis conocimientos de catalán son prácticamente nulos, no tengo herramientas para juzgar.

No sé en qué variante del catalán "guin" significa "hijo" ni "ovart" significa "terreno pantanoso o desolado". En ese mismo enlace dice al mismo tiempo que <<Proviene del término "Guinovert", que significa "caña verde" en catalán antiguo>>... No me fío nada.
